# How to list only child categories?

Tags: categories

Is there any way to list the child categories only? I just want to filter the Parent Categories

Comment: What have you tried from [`get_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories)?

Comment: I was missing `exclude` in `get_categories` it is working now some how. But i have to give the ids manually, is there any way to block the parents?

Comment: To answer this, you'd better give more details in the Question itself: >>[edit]<<.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is to display the subcategory instead of parent .
I am not sure this is the one as you are trying too.

```
 <ul> 
    <?php 
     $catsy = get_the_category();
     $myCat = $catsy->cat_ID;
        wp_list_categories('orderby=id&child_of='.$myCat); 
    ?>
    </ul>
```